# Is there a way I can verify client_id and client secret for Facebook OAuth?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I am creating an Facebook oauth plugin which let admin enter the appid and secret in a form and use this to communicate to facebook.

Is there any way I can check whether the entered data is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Generate an App Token with the ID/Secret and use the /application endpoint with it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/application#Reading

More information about Access Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/